# can i compile hydro with gcc 4.8

Tags: ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

specifically, i am interested in compiling with cxx11, and gcc4.8 offers a cxx11 implementation (invoked with an appropriate flag) that we would like to use.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220777/can-i-compile-hydro-with-gcc-4.8/) by [legalup](https://answers.ros.org/users/25072/legalup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is likely that you can get it to work. It's not tested or supported so expect to have to patch some things to make it work.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0